# How to retrieve session information from a different page in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is where the data that is entered is displayed. At the moment it's only displaying the email, it wont display phone, city and county.I would like to display all this information for a specific user

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if(!($_SESSION['email'])){
        header("location: login.php");

    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <style type='text/css'>
    body{
        background:url('wellcome.png');
    }
    </style>
    <body><b>Welcome you have succesfully logged into your account</b>
    <p></p>
    <font color='red' size='5'><?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>
    </font>
    <font color='red' size='5'><?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>
    <font color='red' size='5'><?php echo $_SESSION['phone'];?>
    <font color='red' size='5'><?php echo $_SESSION['city'];?>
    <font color='red' size='5'><?php echo $_SESSION['county'];?>
    </font>
    <h1 align='right' style='margin-right:50px; margin-top:50px'>
    <a href='logout.php'>Logout Here</a></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is where the user enters data:

```
    <html>

    <head>
    <title>Registration Forma</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method='post' action='registration.php'>
    <table width='400' border='5' align='center'>
          <tr>
            <td colspan = '5'><h1>Registration Form</h1></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td align = 'center'>User Name:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='name'/></td>
            </tr>

            <td align = 'center'>Phone Number:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='phone'/></td>
            </tr>
            <td align = 'center'>County:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='county'/></td>
            </tr>
            <td align = 'center'>City/Town:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='city'/></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>

            <td align = 'center'>User Paswword:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='pass'/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td align = 'center'>Email:</td>
            <td><input type ='text' name='email' /></td>
            </tr>

          <tr>
          <td colspan='5' align='center'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='sign up' /></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <center><B>Already Registered </b> <a href='login.php'>Login here</a></center>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php

      $servername = "localhost"; 
    $username = "root"; $password = ""; 
    $dbname = "users_db";
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
         { echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     } 
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { $user_name = $_POST['name']; 
     $user_pass = $_POST['pass']; 
     $user_email = $_POST['email']; 
     $Phone = $_POST['phone']; 
     $County = $_POST['county']; 
     $City = $_POST['city']; 
     if($user_name=='') 
     { echo "<script>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>"; 
    exit(); } 
    if($user_pass=='') 
    { echo "<script>alert('Please enter your password!')</script>"; 
    exit(); } if($user_email=='') 
    { echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email!')</script>";
     exit(); } 
     //CHECKING FIELDS 
     $check_username = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$user_name'"; 
     $result_username= mysqli_query($conn, $check_username) or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result_username) > 0) {
         echo "Username already exists, please try another one!";
     exit();
     } 
     $check_email = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$user_email'";
     $result_email = mysqli_query($conn, $check_email) or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result_email) > 0) 
     { echo "Email already exists, please try another one!"; 
    exit(); }
     //INSERTING DATA TO DATABASE
     $insertquery = "INSERT INTO users (user_name,user_pass,user_email,Phone,County,City)
     VALUES ('$user_name','$user_pass','$user_email','$Phone','$County','$City')";
     if (mysqli_query($conn, $insertquery))
         { echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>"; } else {
             echo "Error: " . $insertquery . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); 
             }
             } 

             ?>
```

This is my login page. This is where the user enters their email and password to login. When the user logins in they go into the welcome page, that's where I want them to see their personal details i.e. name, phone, city and county.

```
<?php
session_start()

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<style type='text/css'>
body{
    background:url('back.jpg');
}
</style>
<body>
<form method='post' action='login.php'>
<table width='400' border='5' align='center'>
      <tr>
        <td colspan = '5'><h1>Login Form</h1></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td align = 'center'>Paswword:</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='pass'/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td align = 'center'>Email:</td>
        <td><input type ='text' name='email' /></td>
        </tr>

      <tr>
      <td colspan='5' align='center'><input type='submit' name='login' value='login' /></td>
      </tr>
</table>
</form>
<center>
<font color='red' size='6'>registered yet?
</font><a href ='registration.php'>Sign up here</a>
</body>
</html>

<?php
 $servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; $password = ""; 
$dbname = "users_db";
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];


    $check_email = "select * from users where user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";


    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $check_email) or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 

    if (mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0)
```

{

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($check_email);

$_SESSION['email']=$data['user_email'];
$_SESSION['name']=$data['user_name'];
$_SESSION['phone']=$data['Phone'];
$_SESSION['county']=$data['County'];
$_SESSION['city']=$data['City'];

        echo
        "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        }
        else{   
        echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
        }


}

?>
```

Comment: I dont see where you set the SESSION

Comment: **Is this what you mean ?This is from my login page **                                                        
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 $password = $_POST['pass'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 
 
 $check_email = "select * from users where user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";
 
 
 $run = mysqli_query($conn, $check_email) or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 

 if (mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0) 
 {
  $_SESSION['email']=$email;
  
  
  echo
  "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
  }
      else{ 
  echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
  }
 

}

?>

Comment: Kinda,you only set session for email here `$_SESSION['email']=$email;` Do the same for all others

Comment: I have done that but I still get the same response ,I have edited the question and added in my login page where this session is located ,can you see the mistake now?

Comment: You might want to read up on SQL injection. As it stands, it's trivial to bypass the authentication here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding error_reporting at the start of the php:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    session_start();
```

this will display any errors that occur,
I'm guessing that the problem lies in the login page. You most likely are only setting the email value into the session variable but not the others.

if you add error_reporting it will tell you what is going wrong.

You should find the code where you set `$_SESSION['email']` and add the code to add the other attributes to the `$_SESSION` variable

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$check_email = "select * from users where user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";


$run = mysqli_query($conn, $check_email) or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0) 
{
    // here is where you need to add all the other variables but you need to retrieve them from the mysql request and not the post data which you set above
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($check_email);
    // now i don't know the column names for these but i'm guessing they are user_variable
    $_SESSION['email']=$data['user_email'];
    $_SESSION['name']=$data['user_name'];
    $_SESSION['phone']=$data['user_phone'];
    $_SESSION['city']=$data['user_city'];
    $_SESSION['county']=$data['user_county'];


    echo
    "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else{   
    echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
    }
```

}

Comment: While helpful, this should be a comment. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ceejayoz it should/could definitely lead him to an answer though, and if he gets error messages he can edit his question and i'll further edit my answer? or is this not a correct way to handle this?

Comment: I tried that and I got this reply on the page :Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\xampplite\htdocs\registration\welcome.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: phone in D:\xampplite\htdocs\registration\welcome.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined index: city in D:\xampplite\htdocs\registration\welcome.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined index: county in D:\xampplite\htdocs\registration\welcome.php on line 26

Comment: this means that your variables are never set, you should find the code where you set the $_SESSION['email'] variable (probably in the login page i think) and add the other variables here as well if you want to store them in your session. Undefined index means the that he knows the variable $_SESSION, but he can't find the phone index ($_SESSION['phone']) this would mean it hasn't been set yet.

Comment: if (mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0) 
 {
  $_SESSION['email']=$email;
  $_SESSION['name']=$name;
  
  echo
  "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
  }
      else{ 
  echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
  }
 **I set the session for name and I'm still getting the same response,am I doing something wrong here(This is coming from my login page)

Comment: there is your problem, you're only setting the email and name:
$_SESSION['email']=$email; $_SESSION['name']=$name;
phone, city and county are all not in there? how should php know that he has to add those as well?
i'll update my answer

Comment: i edited my answer but might not work because i don't know what is above the piece of code you just send, can you edit your question and add the complete code.

Comment: I edited the question , I put in  $_SESSION['name']=$name; 
    $_SESSION['phone']=$phone; 
    $_SESSION['city']=$city; 
    $_SESSION['county']=$county;                                                                   but I still got the same error

Comment: i know, that i already see why, it's because of some of the code above it. you should really read up on this first and try to understand how this works. I'll edit my answer so it contains the correct code for the login page which should work.

Comment: @artur actually i don't know what the column names for it are, so i can't give you the correct code without knowing that but let me try and explain the problem.

Comment: @artur i edited the last part of my answer, also read the comments and see if you understand, it's important that you learn and not just copy it. i hope it works like this, there might still be some column names that are different.

Comment: Hmm I tried that  and I changed around the way you have and gave the appropriate column names from mysql database which are  user_name ,user_pass  ,user_email  ,Phone  ,County  ,City and now I m not getting any error message but I m still only get the email back and no other attributes

Comment: are you sure the values are set in the database?

check your database on what the values are.

also you check what is in the $_SESSION variable by adding the following somewhere in php: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Array
(
    [email] => artur2k9@hotmail.com
    [name] => 
    [phone] => 
    [county] => 
    [city] => 
)   Thats what I got when I put in that command

Comment: so that means name phone, county and city are set but they are empty, which would mean that either the column names from your mysql aren't correct or you haven't joined it with the correct table that includes those columns. check you database scheme on where those columns exist, and whether it's not empty for this specific user. (also i'm of to bed soon, any more help will have to wait till tomorrow

Comment: Ok thanks for the help  ,I will try figure it out now

Answer (score 0):

i can't imagine what you mean by "different page" exactly.
Are both webpages stored on the same webserver (e.g.: mywebsite.com/pageA and mywebsite.com/pageA) or on different webservers (e.g.: google.com and bing.com)?

If you want to use $_SESSION[] -
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
that works only on the same website.

Also you need to assign somewhere (maybe on the checkLogin Page / Function) the values from the database to the $_SESSION value.
Maybe you look for the place where $_SESSION['email'] = $databaserow['email'] or something similar is and extend to the values you want, too.
The code you posted doesen't match that.

Comment: By different page I mean the page the user logs into like their profile account page and their personal details are shown